# how #if does work? Do I misunderstand form of #if~#endif?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int LOCAL;
LOCAL JAPAN = 81;
LOCAL KOREA = 82;
LOCAL CHINA = 86;
LOCAL USER_LOCAL = CHINA;

#if (USER_LOCAL == KOREA || USER_LOCAL == JAPAN)
typedef char NAME[20];
#elif (USER_LOCAL == CHINA)
typedef char NAME[5];
#endif


int main()
{
    NAME playername;
    cin >> playername;

    cout << "Welcome, " << playername << "!";
}
```

I changed

```
LOCAL USER_LOCAL = CHINA;
```

to

```
LOCAL USER_LOCAL = 86;
```

I did this changing to similar forms.

then

```
typedef int LOCAL;
LOCAL KOREA = 82;
LOCAL JAPAN = 81;
LOCAL CHINA = 86;
LOCAL USER_LOCAL = 86;

#if (USER_LOCAL == 82 || USER_LOCAL == 81)
typedef char NAME[20];
#elif (USER_LOCAL == 86)
typedef char NAME[5];
#endif
```

The above code works what I intended.

but I want to use country names instead of numbers.
Do I misunderstand how (#if ~ #endif) works?

Comment: If you made a mistake in the question, please update the question rather than adding a comment. It's best to do so *before* anyone posts an answer.

Comment: @jamesdlin : they don't behave exactly the same. In the first code, `USER_LOCAL == KOREA` will evaluate to non-zero since neither has been explicitly defined, and thus both default to `0` (so, `NAME` will be defined as `char[20]`). In the second code, both the `#if` and the `#elif` conditions evaluate to zero, since `USER_LOCAL` hasn't been explicitly defined, and thus can't be equal to any of the provided values (so, `NAME` will be undefined). This doesn't match the op's observation though.

Answer (score 1):

In `#if`, you can only use values that have been initialized with `#define`. This should work as expected:

```
#define JAPAN 81
#define KOREA 82
#define CHINA 86
#define USER_LOCAL CHINA

#if (USER_LOCAL == KOREA || USER_LOCAL == JAPAN)
typedef char NAME[20];
#elif (USER_LOCAL == CHINA)
typedef char NAME[5];
#endif
```

Comment: That's not entirely true.  If you have `#if NONSENSE` and never define `NONSENSE`, then the preprocessor interprets `NONSENSE` as zero (and in this case, executes the `#elif` or `#else` clause if they're present).  That's why the original test `#if (USER_LOCAL == KOREA || USER_LOCAL == JAPAN)` evaluates to 'true'; none of `USER_LOCAL`, `KOREA` or `JAPAN` is defined, so they're all treated as zero, so the condition is true.

Comment: Additionally (and sorry for being pedantic), but there are also symbols that the preprocessor understands that never have a corresponding `#define` (e.g. `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`). Most C compilers also support defining simple preprocessor macros via command line arguments.